# How do I center a list and its items to the page?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/hmaQR/

Here is my html:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1>My Website</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation-wrapper">
        <ul id="top-navigation">
            <li class="home">Home</li>
            <li class="about">About</li>
            <li class="Blog">Blog</li>
            <li class="Contact">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="body"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#page {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 960px;
    height: 700px;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-decoration:;
    color: #0099CC
}
#logo {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
#navigation-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    text-align: center;
}
#top-navigation {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
}
#top-navigation li {
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 5px;
    color: blue;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You'll notice that the orange navbar/list is not quite centered to the logo above it. What the heck am I missing?
I cannot seem to get the #top-navigation to center to the middle of the page. I'm super new to css, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you in each css file of a page that you make, always put the following first to disable all margin and padding of the default css:

```
* { margin:0;padding:0}
```

Try that, and then you can tweak the margin and padding of your h1

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmaQR/1/

```
ul { padding-left: 0; }
```

I highly recommend getting a good dev toolbar. Chrome has a great one out of the box.